# Why doesn't this ruby code throw an exception?

Tags: ruby

I am working through Bruce Tate's **Seven Languages in Seven Weeks**, and attempting to do all of the exercises. There is a Tree exercise in which the user is to change *only* the initializer to accept a hash and create a tree from it. My initial attempt was the following:

```
def initialize(hash={})
  if !hash.keys[0].nil?
    @node_name = hash.keys[0]
    @children = []
    if !(hash.values[0].nil? or hash.values[0] == {})
      hash.values[0].each do |k, v|
        @children.push(Tree.new({k => v})
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This works. However, code without the checks also works, i.e.:

```
def initialize(hash={})
  @node_name = hash.keys[0]
  @children = []
  hash.values[0].each do |k, v|
    @children.push(Tree.new({k => v})
  end
end
```

Why are the checks not required? It seems like I would get something like a null reference (I come from a .Net background, so it may be called something else in ruby).

Here is my full code:

```
class Tree
  attr_accessor :children, :node_name

    def initialize(hash={})
      @node_name = hash.keys[0]
      @children = []
      hash.values[0].each do |k, v|
        @children.push(Tree.new({k => v})
      end
    end

  def visit_all(&block)
    visit &block
    children.each{|c| c.visit_all &block}
  end

  def visit(&block)
    block.call self
  end
end


ruby_tree = Tree.new({"grampa" => { "dad" => { "son1" => {}, "son2" => {}}, "uncle" => { "nephew1" => {}, "nephew2" => {"youngun1" => {}}}}})

puts "Visiting a node"
ruby_tree.visit {|node| puts node.node_name}
puts

puts "visiting entire tree"
ruby_tree.visit_all {|node| puts node.node_name}
```

Comment: A small thing: you could write `@children = hash.values[0].map { |k, v| Tree.new(k => v) }`. Ruby allows you to write a hash without the braces when it's an argument.

Comment: Just for completeness' sake: there are no null references in Ruby. Ever. Any reference will always be to a valid object.

Comment: Ah. So at worst, it would be a NoSuchMerhod on a Nil object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove the `if` condition from this code:

```
if !(hash.values[0].nil? or hash.values[0] == {})
  hash.values[0].each do |v|
    k = hash.key(v)
    @children.push(Tree.new({k => v})
  end
end
```

you can get an exception in this case:

```
hash = {}
hash.values       # => []
hash.values[0]    # => nil
```

Iif you run `each` loop on it without checking the condition, it will fail as `each` is not defined on `nil`.

Your second condition `hash.values[0] == {}` may be skipped at all.

This is just a short cut to prevent the `each` loop on an empty hash as looping on it will have no effect.

```
hash = { foo: {} }
hash.values[0]     # => {}
```

Now doing `{}.each` will have no effect on the output.

Answer (score 0):

You will only get an exception if you try to call a method on `nil` -- then you'll get a NoMethodError. Since you've passed in valid hashes the checks don't matter. If you explicitly passed `nil` in as the argument to `new` when you create your `ruby_tree`, you will see a NoMethodError

Additionally, the line

```
hash.values[0].each do |k, v|
```

won't work as you expect. Calling `hash.values` returns an Array, and the iterator for Arrays only yields one item to the block (the element in the next position in the array). Instead you should use `hash.each do |k, v|`